# Cannot use overloaded operator of struct defined inside function

Tags: swift, operator-overloading

I have a struct defined inside a function and would like define and use an overloaded operator on that struct:

```
func test() {
    struct Foo {
        let value: Int

        static func +(left: Foo, right: Foo) -> Foo {
            return Foo(value: left.value + right.value)
        }
    }

    print(Foo(value: 2) + Foo(value: 3))
}
```

But this does not work and I get the following error:

```
test.swift:10:25: error: binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two 'Foo' operands
    print(Foo(value: 2) + Foo(value: 3))
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.swift:10:25: note: overloads for '+' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (Float, Float), (Double, Double), (Float80, Float80), (UInt8, UInt8), (Int8, Int8), (UInt16, UInt16), (Int16, Int16), (UInt32, UInt32), (Int32, Int32), (UInt64, UInt64), (Int64, Int64), (UInt, UInt), (Int, Int), (String, String), (C, S), (S, C), (RRC1, RRC2), (Self, Self.Stride), (Self.Stride, Self), (UnsafeMutablePointer<Pointee>, Int), (Int, UnsafeMutablePointer<Pointee>), (UnsafePointer<Pointee>, Int), (Int, UnsafePointer<Pointee>)
    print(Foo(value: 2) + Foo(value: 3))
                        ^
```

Is it just not suppoerted to define operators on non-global structs or am I missing something? Are there any options to make this work without moving the struct to the file scope?

Comment: Related bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3092. I’d still file a specific report for this issue though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a struct with overload and then use it in the same function. In compilation time, the overload will not be known. 
So you have to put the struct outside the function like this

```
struct Foo{
    let value: Int


    static func +(lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Foo {
        return Foo(value: lhs.value + rhs.value)
    }
}

func test() {

    print(Foo(value: 2) + Foo(value: 3))
}
```

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? Otherwise I'm inclined to file this as a bug because IMHO there should be an error on the definition of the operator.